# Activity Diagram how to continue code flow in one chart

Tags: uml

I have a function.
Which for example goes like this:

```
Function start: 
...
 if statement{
      set variable 
 }

if second if{}

contintue
```

This code I try to put into a UML, Activity diagram. 
[image]

I wondered if my forking is done right, or do I need to use a forking symbol. So I have a split where it eventually gets into the if statement ( difference in totals). But after the if (or even if the if is not even executed) the  next if statement will be executed (regardless of first if result).

Comment: I don't see how the code snippet and the diagram are related in any way. Also the code snipped does not look like it would be any meaningful code.

Comment: the snippet is no real code its just to show how the code can go and how to draw a activity if there are 2 if statements or if there is just an if statement and the code continues after the if statements.. is this drawing above sufficient for that...

Comment: No. That's incorrect. You can not split below the middle 2nd action. That would imply a fork and parallel execution.

Comment: Thanks man if you can put it in answer then I can accept your answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have conditional paths you need to use decision nodes. Imagine a virtual token to represent the execution flow. When you are at an action that has multiple (unguarded) control flows leaving it, each will take a token (the UML spec calls that implicit fork) an execution will continue in parallel. So either you add guards to each of the outgoing control flows or you use a decision node. Though you should (or better must) use guards here too you have only a single token that will leave the decision node. Without proper guards it will be undecided which of the outgoing flows will take the token.

Implicit fork: 
[image]

Only one token continues: [image]

One token for sure and eventually a 2nd in parallel:[image]

(I'm not 100% sure if that's really true. It's a notation I'd never use.)

Only one token continues, but not defined which (due to no guards): [image]